# How do i parse an NSString to get the words and operators separately in 2 different arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a String

```
NSString *formula = @"base+unit1-unit2*unit3/unit4";
```

I am able to get all the words in an array using code :

```
NSArray *myWords = [formula componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-*/"]];

//myWords = {base , unit1,unit2,unit3,unit4}
```

but  i am facing problem in getting all the operators in an array like
 this myOperators = {+,-,*,/}
Please advice thanks

Comment: What you got in above>?

Comment: I would guess you'd use some sort of tokenizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NSScanner` to walk through the string extracting all of the parts you need (see `scanCharactersFromSet:intoString:` and `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:`).

Comment: thanks got the desired result using scanCharactersFromSet:intoString

Answer (score 1):

You could use NSRegularExpression to accomplish that. A quick solution could be:

```
NSString *formula = @"base+unit1-unit2*unit3/unit4";
NSRegularExpression *testExpression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[*-/]"
                                                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

[testExpression enumerateMatchesInString:formula
                                 options:0
                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, formula.length)
                              usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
                              NSLog(@"%@", [formula substringWithRange:result.range]); 
}];
```

you can build a mutable Array within that block with all the operators found according to the regular expression.

The regular expression ist just a quick example - you could create something more fancy than that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a character set containing all characters except your operators using invertedSet

```
NSCharacterSet *operatorCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-/*"];
NSCharacterSet *otherCharacters = [operatorCharacters invertedSet];    

NSArray *operatorComponents = [formula componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                            otherCharacters];
```

You'll then want to remove any empty strings from a mutable copy of the array

```
NSMutableArray *mutableOperators = [operatorComponents mutableCopy];
[mutableOperators removeObject:@""];
```

Comment: That will create a lot of empty strings in the Array which has to be filtered to get the final result as it separates the string after EVERY occurrence of ANY of that characters.

Comment: I'll add how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? 
(psudocode):

```
for character in string:

    if character is one of +, -, /, *:

        add to array

return array
```