# how to convert this string @"base+unit1+unit2(unit3+unit4)" into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to convert `NSString *formula = @"base+unit1+unit2(unit3+unit4)";`
into an array `{base,+,unit1,+,unit2,(,unit3,+,unit4,)}`

Can anybody solve this.

Comment: How is this really different to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21332642/how-do-i-parse-an-nsstring-to-get-the-words-and-operators-separately-in-2-differ ?

Comment: am able to get the contents of the string in two different arrays but in the above scenario i need it in a single array as they appear(left->right) in the above string

Comment: Fine, but the same solution will work, just add the results to a single array as you scan...

Comment: I'm thinking there's an expression parser class, but I'm not finding it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *formula = @"base+unit1+unit2(unit3+unit4)";
formula =[formula stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@",+,"];
formula =[formula stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@",(,"];
formula =[formula stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@",),"];
if([[formula substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(formula.length-1,1)] isEqualToString:@","])
    formula = [formula substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,formula.length-1)];
NSArray *items = [formula componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"Needed array %@",items);
```

You can also use the above type of codes to get the req soln.

Comment: There will be a comma at the end of the string, you need to trim it.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+()"];
NSArray *elements = [inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:charSet];
```

**EDIT** Actually, that won't work, as the `+`, `(` and `)` characters won't appear in the array.  Oh well.